# How to do SEO for front-page.php using Yoast plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, yoast

My wordpress themplate uses front-page.php as the site front page, so it is not showing in pages list. How can I do seo for this page using the yoast plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can set SEO related settings in page which is currently set as static home page from settings->reading options
you will get SEO settings below pages content in edit page of your front page

Comment: My theme uses front-page.php file as the home page, so we can't see the home page in the pages list.
In settings->reading options  homepage displays is set as 'Your latest posts'

Comment: I got your issue, so now you just create one new page name as Home and just select static page from settings->reading and select Home page from dropdown and save options
step2: go to pages and edit home page you will get that options related to SEO

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

You can update the SEO title and meta description of your front-page template via Yoast by going to the "SEO" entry in the dashboard → Search Appearance → General → Homepage.

Here you'll see the "SEO title" and "Meta description" fields.